# lldb error: couldn't IRGen expression: Clang importer error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lldb

I have an iOS project written in swift running on the simulator. (xcode 15.2, SDK 17.2) When trying to print an expression in the lldb console, I get the following error:

> couldn't IRGen expression: Clang importer error

This is followed by a changing cast of what look like clang errors, sometimes about undefined variables in system headers, or missing symbols.

This is different than other IRGen errors discussed on stackoverflow, and the solutions there didn't work. I have of course deleted my derived data.

Comment: When a a swift module imports C/ObjC/C++ API's its types are represented by a "clang module" built from the headers containing those API's.  To reconstruct this type world in the lldb, it must rebuild this clang module.  If it can't do that, then it won't be able to support expression evaluation (though variable viewing with `v` will still work.)  However, there are many reasons why clang importation might fail; just the headline message is not sufficient to diagnose any particular failure.  The `swift-healthcheck` command gathers the relevant info, useful for a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by clearing the clang module cache found in `/var/folders/[short directory name]/[long alphanumeric name]/C/clang/ModuleCache`. [Jim Ingham's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77833406/lldb-error-couldnt-irgen-expression-clang-importer-error#comment137218076_77833406) provided the necessary clue. There must've been something wrong with the modules in that cache.